# How to detect if a website is map oriented using Android's Webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I've noticed that Firefox Android app's address-bar position is fixed when browsing a map oriented website (such as Google Maps, MapQuest, etc.), opposed to other sites (where the bar's position is dynamic). 
So, in order to add a similar feature to a browser app I'm currently developing, how can I make this detection myself?

Comment: my guess here based on how Android works is that this is based on scrolling behavior and touch event. And nothing to do directly to the actual mapping feature. For example, because the map consumes every touch event, the browser doesn't know when to hide, so never does. So that's something for you to dig into.

Comment: I understand that websites which have a fixed bar may have a special characteristic which is broader than displaying a map. Since I couldn't find any non-mapping websites which demonstrate it, I chose to focus on the mapping aspect. Its not purely related to scrolling though, since the contents of many other sites can be scrolled and dragged and yet Firefox's bar does not stay fixed while browsing them.

Comment: I understand, but I guess you focused on the wrong part of my comment. I guess the interesting part for you might be to check the scrolling behavior and/or touch events. Possible pointers could be in `ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(...)` or combination of `ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(...)` with `View.onTouchEvent(...)`. I believe there is where you gonna find your answer.

Comment: Hmm, I get it now.. alright, might worth a try! thank you.